# Trying to make this method generic but cannot get around type errors in visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to refactor this code to be dynamic so that no matter what entity I pass in, the method will return the correct type from the jsonformatter in our web API. But I keep getting compiler errors.

I've tried using the dynamic keyword, extracting the type from the parameter being passed in.

From controller:

```
        IEnumerable<LoadsViewModel> loads = null;

        loads = APIMethods.GetDataFromAPIAsync("stats", loads);

        return View(loads);
```

from Method:

```
public static class APIMethods
{

    public static async Task<IEnumerable<dynamic>> GetDataFromAPIAsync(string controllerURI, Type type)
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();

        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
        try
        {

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:50000" + controllerURI);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           // list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<entity.GetType>>(apiResponse);
            list = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(apiResponse, type);
            return list;
        }

        catch (HttpRequestException ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
            return list;
        }
        finally
        {
            handler.Dispose();
            client.Dispose();
        }
    }


}
```

Error 1:

> Error  CS1503  Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Type'

Error 2:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Type' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: Why are you passing `IEnumerable<LoadsViewModel> loads` as the second parameter to a method that expects a `Type`?

Comment: I want to be able to pass in any Enumerable entity into the method. I don't know what I'm allowed to do to pass in a type at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you're mixing generics and dynamic. There's no need to do that. Declare your method to use List, and adjust accordingly:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetDataFromAPIAsync<T>(string controllerURI)
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => { return true; };
    try
    {

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:50000" + controllerURI);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(apiResponse);
        return list;
    }

    catch (HttpRequestException ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        return list;
    }
    finally
    {
        handler.Dispose();
        client.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Call it like this:

```
MyType foo = await GetDataFromAPIAsync<MyType>("foos/1");
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting an error when I call the method:loads = APIMethods.GetDataFromAPIAsync<LoadsViewModel>("stats");' 
 
     Cannot implicitly convert type System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dashboards.Models.DataViewModels.LoadsViewModel>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Dashboards.Models.DataViewModels.LoadsViewModel>'

Comment: `loads = await APIMethods.GetDataFromAPIAsync<LoadsViewModel>("stats");` You should consider reading about async/await